# How does the video BIOS fit in the boot process?

Tags: boot, bios, uefi, gpu

I'm trying to understand how the boot process works and the differences that exist between legacy BIOS and UEFI, but when it comes to the video BIOS, I can't find much information except a small article on Wikipedia.

As for my understanding, the video BIOS's main job is to provide a basic interface for displaying characters and 2D images during the boot process.

However, I can't find an answer to the following questions:

1. Wikipedia says that BIOS/UEFI loads the video BIOS early in the boot sequence, but it also says:

   > The system BIOS loads the video BIOS from the card's ROM into system RAM and transfers control to it early in the boot sequence.

   Does that mean that the rest of the boot process is actually executed by the video BIOS, and not the motherboard's BIOS/UEFI? Or does it mean that the video BIOS, after being loaded, once it finishes to do something (what exactly?), transfers control back to the system BIOS/UEFI, which then completes the boot sequence?
2. Is there such a thing as video UEFI, as opposed to video BIOS?

   I often see GPUs that claim to be UEFI-ready, but I don't understand what does that really mean (besides the fact that a non-UEFI-ready GPU isn't compatible with a UEFI system. But why?)

Is the difference between a video UEFI and video BIOS the same existing between a motherboard's legacy BIOS and UEFI? (which wouldn't make much sense if the video BIOS/UEFI isn't in charge of completing the boot sequence) Or is there something else that I'm (probably) overlooking?

Comment: The __transfer__ of the video is for a software operating system like Windows to start the loading of the video drivers. I am not aware of any difference with UEFI or BIOS as far as the video goes. BIOS starts with a normal VGA and allows the OS to take over to whatever the system needs. Special drivers for the video card, etc.  GPU's being UEFI-ready, I think, means the compatiblilty of the BIOS.

Comment: @vssher Wikipedia states that the video BIOS is given control **early** in the boot process, when there is no OS loaded at all.

Comment: No matter how early the operating system which takes control still has to configure and talk with the BIOS, be it UEFI or legacy BIOS all information has to go through the BIOS to communicate with the hardware. The BIOS is controlling the motherboard.

Comment: @vssher sorry, I'm not following. I'm starting from the assumption that during the boot process, the CPU can only run one program at once. If control is given to the video BIOS, how can the motherboard's BIOS/UEFI complete the boot sequence? Besides, you seem to be only focusing on the OS, but from what I know the video BIOS is also used to display things like the BIOS/UEFI's user interface.

Comment: If you could make an answer addressing my questions and explaining in detail how the video BIOS fit in the entire boot sequence, I'd be glad.

Comment: __I can't find much information except a small article on Wikipedia.__ Where is this article? You are doing research, I see, what is your source. What do you mean when you say, "Besides, you seem to be only focusing on the OS...." I thought this was part of your question. You have what, three questions where you really should have only one? Good luck with your researching I am trying to help someone.

Comment: @vssher I appreciate your help. This the Wikipedia article I was referring to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_BIOS I'm not trying to understand (only) what the video BIOS does, but (especially) how it fits in the overall boot sequence, which from my understanding is a pretty linear process.

Comment: Video "BIOS" is simply the Basic Input Output System of the graphics card. It does not control the booting of your computer, it only allows things to be displayed onscreen. For example, the computer brand, BIOS menu, or whatever you see displayed right after you power on the computer. The wiki is confusingly phrased. Control of the system is not given to the VBIOS, control of the VBIOS is given to the system.

Comment: @fuzzydrawings what I can't understand is how the CPU can run two BIOSes at the same time. Or is the video BIOS actually run by the graphics processor?

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same misunderstanding while reading exactly the same Wikipedia page a time ago, so I wanted to answer this question even 2 years later.

> 1. Does that mean that the rest of the boot process is actually executed by the video BIOS, and not the motherboard's BIOS/UEFI? Or does it mean that the video BIOS, after being loaded, once it finishes to do something (what exactly?), transfers control back to the system BIOS/UEFI, which then completes the boot sequence?

Second. The Video BIOS is just [a kind of BIOS extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Option_ROM&oldid=1119519196#Video) that the main BIOS trusts enough so it can transfer the control flow to. And yes, the extension **may** not return control if it wants (and this behavior was applied in some cases), but this makes no sense in case of Video BIOS.

> 2. Is there such a thing as video UEFI, as opposed to video BIOS?

Yes, the Video BIOS was [superseded](http://web.archive.org/web/20190423035154/http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/intelligent-systems/intel-embedded-graphics-drivers/faq-bios-firmware.html) (see #3) by the "GOP Driver" ([GOP](https://wiki.osdev.org/index.php?title=GOP&oldid=27450) stands for Graphics Output Protocol, and "driver" for UEFI is the same as "Option ROM" for BIOS). If you're also interested, there's also a thing called [VBIOS Hybrid Image](https://event.msi.com/2014/vga/Hybrid_BIOS/) exists, which literally is a combination of the GOP driver and the Video BIOS, designed to support both legacy and UEFI-equipped platforms.

> I often see GPUs that claim to be UEFI-ready, but I don't understand what does that really mean (besides the fact that a non-UEFI-ready GPU isn't compatible with a UEFI system. But why?)

This means that such a video card is able to operate with UEFI directly, i.e. not in the CSM (Compatibility Support Module) mode that is mostly known simply as "Legacy Mode". Also I've noticed [some claims](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2183250-bios-change-from-uefi-mode-to-legacy-mode-after-installing-nvs295-graphics-card#entry-8140096) that UEFI motherboards could fallback to that mode if non-UEFI video card is detected. The reverse case with UEFI-only video cards on BIOS systems [can also be workarounded](https://old.reddit.com/r/lowendgaming/comments/pky5r6/are_there_any_issues_with_new_gpus_on_old_preuefi/).

> Is the difference between a video UEFI and video BIOS the same existing between a motherboard's legacy BIOS and UEFI?

Actually "Video BIOS" is a kinda misleading wording because there's no such thing as "a separate BIOS for video card". It's just a silly blob of code (a bunch of instructions for the 80x86 processor being in 16-bit Real Mode) whose main purpose is to initialize the video card properly by setting its registers etc. and then provide an implementation for the handler of [#10<sub>hex</sub> interrupt](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=INT_10H&oldid=1060426954) by setting the corresponding pointer value in the [Interrupt Vector Table (IVT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Interrupt_descriptor_table&oldid=1100199467#Real_mode).

---

For further reading:

- Option ROM (a.k.a. BIOS Extensions / BIOS Expansion):

  1. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS#Extensions_(option_ROMs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=BIOS&oldid=1122365436#Extensions_(option_ROMs))
  2. [http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~xyfeng/research/cos/resources/machine/biosextension.htm](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/%7Exyfeng/research/cos/resources/machine/biosextension.htm)
  3. https://www.rigacci.org/docs/biblio/online/firmware/romext.htm
  4. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/uefi-validation-option-rom-validation-guidance
  5. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E20881_01/html/E20896/sbxis.glink.html
- IBM PC startup sequence:

  6. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting#Boot_sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Booting&oldid=1127133838#Boot_sequence)
  7. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test#IBM-compatible_PC_POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Power-on_self-test&oldid=1119414461#IBM-compatible_PC_POST)
  8. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI#Boot_stages](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=UEFI&oldid=1127043108#Boot_stages)
  9. [https://wiki.osdev.org/System_Initialization_(x86)](https://wiki.osdev.org/index.php?title=System_Initialization_(x86)&oldid=25380)
  10. http://web.archive.org/web/20200120051830/http://philipstorr.id.au/pcbook/book1/post.htm
  11. [https://minuszerodegrees.net/5150/motherboard/IBM 5150 - Startup sequence.htm](https://minuszerodegrees.net/5150/motherboard/IBM%205150%20-%20Startup%20sequence.htm)
- General concepts:

  12. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_interrupt_call#Interrupt_table](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=BIOS_interrupt_call&oldid=1123223568#Interrupt_table)
  13. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_Memory_Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Upper_memory_area&oldid=1068332418)
  14. [https://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupt_Vector_Table](https://wiki.osdev.org/index.php?title=Interrupt_Vector_Table&oldid=13993)
  15. ["Do UEFI specifications completely replace the BIOS?"](https://superuser.com/questions/1155287/do-uefi-specifications-completely-replace-the-bios)
  16. [Does UEFI run on top of BIOS?](https://superuser.com/questions/1450261/does-uefi-run-on-top-of-bios)
  17. [Where can I learn all about the PC Video BIOS?](https://superuser.com/questions/241538/where-can-i-learn-all-about-the-pc-video-bios)